# When does IIS call CGlobalModule::OnGlobalApplicationResolveModules?

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-8

I have created a native module for **IIS 7, 7.5 and 8.0**. The module is registered within the IIS configuration and is loaded when an application pool is initialized.

The module's RegisterModule export, creates and registers a descendant of `CGlobalModule` using the supplied `IHttpModuleRegistrationInfo` instance.

The `CGlobalModule` descendant is registered for `GL_APPLICATION_RESOLVE_MODULES`, `GL_APPLICATION_STOP` and `GL_STOP_LISTENING`.

The module's `OnGlobalApplicationResolveModules` method has been given "first" priority during registration.

During a request and when the IIS application pool is recycled, the global module receives the `GL_APPLICATION_STOP` and `GL_STOP_LISTENING` requests as expected. Unfortunately, the `OnGlobalApplicationResolveModules` method is not called under any circumstances that I have been able to determine.

The `CGlobalModule` documentation and sample code on the MSDN do not indicate under what circumstances the `OnGlobalApplicationResolveModules` method is called.

Has anyone successfully used the `OnGlobalApplicationResolveModules` notification? If so, in what circumstances is it executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GL_APPLICATION_RESOLVE_MODULES notification is only sent if the application pool is configured to use .Net Framework 4.0.